# Como acelerar procedimiento MYSQL muy pesado basado en bucle (Mala praxis)

Tags: mysql

He realizado un procedimiento en un bucle, pero me parece bastante precario, lo cual lo lleva a un proceso demasiado lentro para ser MYSQL, alrededor de 15 minutos. El procedimiento es el siguiente

```
DELIMITER \
    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `actualizarbasededatos`()
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT ''
    BEGIN
    DECLARE x INT(11); 
    SET x = (SELECT id FROM productos ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1);
    REPEAT
    IF ifnull((SELECT codigobarras FROM productos WHERE x=id AND eliminado = 0), ")) != " AND ifnull((SELECT codigobarras FROM codigobarras WHERE idproducto = x),") = ifnull((SELECT codigobarras FROM productos WHERE x=id AND eliminado = 0), "))  THEN
    INSERT INTO codigobarras (codigobarras, idproducto) SELECT codigobarras, id FROM productos WHERE id = x;
    END IF;
    IF (IFNULL((SELECT id FROM precios WHERE x=idproducto AND numerodepreciodelista = 0 limit 1), -1)) = -1 AND (IFNULL((SELECT id FROM productos WHERE x=id AND eliminado = 0 limit 1), -1)) != -1 THEN
    INSERT INTO precios (precio, precio2, idproducto, numerodepreciodelista) SELECT precio, precio2, id, 0 FROM productos WHERE id=x;
    END IF;
    SET x = x + 1;
    UNTIL x > (select id from productos order by id desc limit 1) END REPEAT;
    SET x = (SELECT id FROM tickets ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1);
    REPEAT
    IF (select total from tickets WHERE id = x) != (ifnull((SELECT SUM(transaccion) FROM contabilidad WHERE    tipodetransaccion ='pago' and ticketid = x),0)) THEN    
    IF (ifnull((SELECT SUM(transaccion) FROM contabilidad WHERE tipodetransaccion ='pago' and ticketid = x),0)) = 0 THEN    
    INSERT INTO contabilidad (tipodetransaccion, ticketid, transaccion, formadepago) VALUES ('pago', x, (SELECT total FROM tickets WHERE id = x), 'Efectivo');
    END IF;
    END IF;
    SET x = x + 1;
    UNTIL x > (select id from tickets order by id desc limit 1)  END REPEAT;
    END
\ DELIMITER;
```

El procedimiento lo que realiza es una actualización de la estructura en la base de datos, donde los pagos de los tickets se puedan llevar en una tabla independiente, ademas los códigos de barras de los productos se registren también en otra tabla aparte.
El funcionamiento de la misma es mas optima y me parece mucho mejor por eso el cambio, el problema es que la actualización, el proceso este tarda demasiado como ya dije.
El código siguiente se refiere a la estructura de la base de datos
**Tabla codigobarras**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `codigobarras`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `codigobarras` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idproducto` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `codigobarras` text NOT NULL,
  `idrubro` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3891 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**Tabla productos**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `productos`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `productos` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `promocionid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `nombre` text NOT NULL,
  `tipodeproducto` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `cantidadbultocerrado` decimal(10,3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.000',
  `cantidadbultoabierto` decimal(10,3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.000',
  `especial` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ganancia` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `impuesto` decimal(3,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `ultimamodificacion` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `ingresosbrutos` decimal(3,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `categoria` char(5) NOT NULL,
  `proveedor` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `cantidad` decimal(11,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `stockminimo` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '4',
  `precio` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `costo` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `precio2` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `pesoprecio` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1.00',
  `fecha` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `codigobarras` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `imagen` blob,
  `eliminado` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9031 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**Tabla tickets**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tickets`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tickets` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fecha` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `anulacion` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `pagadocon` decimal(11,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `total` decimal(11,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `formadepago` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `descuento` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `cuentacorriente` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `empleado` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `rubro` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `financiamiento` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `recargodeformadepago` decimal(11,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `recargofinanciamiento` decimal(11,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `cuotas` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `terminal` text,
  `deuda` decimal(11,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `retiro` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `pago` decimal(11,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `senacliente` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=142 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Hasta aquí las tablas antiguas, le haré algunas optimizaciones, y creación de indices, en la actualización, pero ese asunto no es importante en este momento.
Las tablas siguientes son creadas para el fin de la "actualización de la base de datos". Como hice referencia anteriormente, la actualización mas que nada comprende en optimizar las consultas a la base de datos futuras. Por eso la separación de datos, para poder crear indices.

**Tabla contabilidad**

```
CREATE TABLE `contabilidad` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `ticketid` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `cuentacorriente` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `empleado` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `fecha` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `interesfinanciero` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
    `interesformadepago` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
    `cuotas` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
    `transaccion` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
    `anulado` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `idgasto` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `valordecuota` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
    `valorfinal` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
    `tipodetransaccion` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `formadepago` TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=131
;
```

**Tabla Precios**

```
CREATE TABLE `precios` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `porcentaje` DECIMAL(4,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
    `precio` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
    `precio2` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
    `idproducto` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `numerodepreciodelista` INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `ganancia` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
    `costo` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
    `impuesto` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
    `ingresosbrutos` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `idproducto` (`idproducto`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=5563
;
```

Aquí con todas las estructuras se puede dar cuenta como funciona el procedimiento, Simplemente se ejecutaría una vez. Pero la idea es que sea mas rápido, y obviamente funciona pero muy lento. Desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: Estoy con ello, sólo avisar a otros que quieran reproducir el problema que al crear el procedimiento hay que precederlo de un "`DELIMITER \`" para que funcione.

Comment: Obviamente hacer la misma consulta una y otra vez por ejemplo para saber si se acaba un repeat es una locura.. Bastaba con hacerla al principio una vez y guardar eso en una variable. pero mas alla de eso, que es lo que quieres lograr con todo este codigo? definitivamente hacer if sobre querys por cada variables es algo que esta mal... todo deberia resolverse en algunos querys, sin tener que repetir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La principal optimización que haría, es en realidad la reescritura de todo el código por sentencias de `INSERT` directas, sin pasar por ciclos y verificaciones innecesarias que suele ser sumamente costoso en cuanto a rendimiento. Voy a tratar de reducir conceptualmente cada uno de los `INSERT`, por favor verifica si el razonamiento que hago es el correcto.

En primer lugar queremos insertar en `codigobarras` aquellos productos de `productos` que NO estén eliminados (`eliminados = 0`) y que obviamente no existan en `codigobarras`. Esto lo podrías resolver así:

```
INSERT INTO codigobarras (codigobarras, idproducto) 
SELECT  p.codigobarras, 
        p.id 
    FROM productos p
    LEFT JOIN codigobarras c
        ON c.idproducto = p.id
    WHERE c.idproducto IS NULL
          AND p.eliminado = 0;
```

La siguiente operación sería insertar en `precios` aquellos `productos` que no existieran en la lista de precios 0 y que no estén eliminados (`eliminados = 0`):

```
INSERT INTO precios (precio, precio2, idproducto, numerodepreciodelista)
SELECT  p.precio, 
        p.precio2, 
        p.id, 
        0
    FROM productos p
    LEFT JOIN precios l
        ON l.idproducto = p.id
        AND l.numerodepreciodelista = 0
    WHERE   l.idproducto IS NULL
            AND p.eliminado = 0;
```

La última operación es la que me generó más dudas. Me desconcierta el control que haces entre `ticket.total`  y la suma de `contabilidad.transaccion`, me hace pensar que en tu caso los `tickets` tiene varios pagos y con cada uno buscas actualizar `contabilidad`, el tema es que si es así, no me cierra que insertes directamente el `total` del ticket. Por lo que veo más lógico que intentas insertar en `contabilidad` cada `ticket` nuevo. Esto lo podrías resolver así:

```
INSERT INTO contabilidad (tipodetransaccion, ticketid, transaccion, formadepago)
SELECT 'pago', 
    t.id, 
    t.total,
    'Efectivo'
    FROM tickets t
    LEFT JOIN  contabilidad c
        ON c.ticketid = t.id
        AND c.tipodetransaccion ='pago' 
    WHERE c.ticketid IS NULL
```

Reemplazar tus ciclos por las tres sentencias `INSERT+SELECT` sin duda va a tener un impacto sumamente positivo en el rendimiento, pero independientemente de esto, la optimización de lo índices, como ya te la han mencionado es otro punto a revisar.

Comment: Gracias patricio!, te comento la ultima, verifica si existe el total ya registrado en contabilidad, como pago, el TOTAL es el valor total de una venta, referiendome a ticket.total, y contabilidad.transaccion seria el pago realizado, si es en varios pagos como tu dices, o tal vez audeuda algo! GRACIAS

Comment: +1 A estas alturas dejo el procedimiento almacenado que había desarrollado. @BernardoHarreguy, quédatelo para tener referencia de cómo hacer las cosas de una manera diferente :)

Answer (score 0):

En mis pruebas simplemente agregando un índice al campo `idproducto` de la tabla `codigobarras` reduzco de 28 segundos a sólo 3 el tiempo de la consulta:

```
ALTER TABLE codigobarras ADD INDEX (idproducto);
```

Estás usando una búsqueda por dicho campo en cada iteración del bucle, pero al no usarlo como índice la búsqueda debe recorrer todos los registros de dicha tabla:

```
SELECT codigobarras FROM productos WHERE x=id AND eliminado = 0
```

Estoy trabajando en convertir los bucles en cursores para optimizar la iteración cuando haya muchos identificadores sin usar (por ahora llevo poco más de un segundo de tiempo de ejecución con la primera parte convertida a cursor).